# POE Switch to Power the PI?

Tags: pi-3, usb-power, switches, poe

Sorry if this a repeated, I couldnt find anything similar. Most threads seems to be modifying the PI or splitting Ethernet.

Will this setup work for powering the PI?

1) Juniper EC-2200 POE Switch 
([https://www.amazon.com/Juniper-Layer-3-Switch-EX2200-C-12P-2G/dp/B005SFPC9G](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005SFPC9G))

2) Ethernet to USB Adapter 
([https://www.amazon.com/UCEC-USB2-0-Ethernet-Adapter-Connector/dp/B011NOVTMO/ref=pd_sim_147_4?ie=UTF8&dpID=41P0HLWcFWL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&psc=1&refRID=V4Y9ZJB0EK6J8BXR4BV2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011NOVTMO))

3) Connect USB to PI's micro USB for power

Will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB/Ethernet device you link to does not say anything about supporting PoE and so, I would assume it doesn't.

The power profile for the two connections is very different, and the logic in the device would need to draw power differently depending on what power was there.  So, if they supported PoE they would be putting extra power handling devices in and require more design work, making it a big selling point to recover those costs.  So, the fact that they *don't* mention it probably means it's not there.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I needed something like this https://www.amazon.com/Raspberry-micro-USB-splitter-adapter-IEEE802-3af/dp/B0108TD78Y/ref=sr_1_7?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1467452739&sr=1-7&keywords=poe+usb

Comment: Yes, that one does look like the right thing (TRT[tm]).  Oh, and thanks for finding it, I'm going to need one myself...

Comment: For future readers, I now have one of these and it's working fine.  The only connection between the RasPi and elsewhere is the 50 foot Ethernet cable, which carries both the power (via PoE) and the network.

Answer (score 2):

You have (2) options to power a Pi from your PoE switch (USB is not one of them):

*[PoE Hat](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/raspberry-pi-poe-hat)*: powers a Pi by just connecting the Ethernet cable to the Pi's Ethernet port; job done.  Presently £20 (inc VAT) from all Pi retailers

*[PoE Splitter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B074Y6M67F/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)*: has two connections: an Ethernet for data and a MicroUSB that diverts the power from the switch to the MicroUSB port cable that plugs into the Pi's standard power port.  Presently £9.90 (inc VAT) on Amazon.co.uk

Both solutions work well, but one might be more suitable in respect to physical form factor form factor of the Pi's enclosure: the PoE hat adds a lot of bulk.

PoE Switch: The one I use- and recommend- is the ZyXEL [GS1900-8HP-GB0102F](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00ID828FQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

And FINALLY, when planning your PoE setup, ensure you chose an appropriate spec Ethernet cable.  At LONGER distances you'll require SMALLER AWG cable.  The *LOWER* the AWG number, the *THICKER* the conductor and *LOWER* the resistance.  If you use a long thin cable to squirt the power long distances, you'll run into issues.

[CAT 6 Ethernet Cables](https://uk.farnell.com/videk/2996-3b/patch-lead-cat6-blue-3m/dp/1525711): I use these Videk 2996-3B CAT 6 AWG 24  3 meter cables and they work well.  £4.06 (ex-VAT) From Farnell

[image: PoE Splitter]

[image: PoE Hat]

Anyhoo, hope this little primer is enough to get you started down the PoE road.